# logical way to clean up a list data type in python

Tags: python, list

Hi guys i get a lot of data in a list data type, and i always get stuck being unable to clean it up. To be more clear, most string data clean up is done using the **split(), strip() and replace()** method. but unfortunately, these methods don't work with a list data type.

```
['2. Skoda\n', '3. Opel\n', '4. Audi\n', '5. Isuzu\n', '6. Acura\n', '7. Subaru \n', '8. Jaguar \n', '9. Jeep\n',
```

'10.Mazda\n', '11.Mini\n', '12.Land Rover\n', '13.Lexus\n', '14.Saab\n', '15.Peugeot \n', '16.Renault \n', '17.Proton\n', '18.Daewoo \n', '19.Citroen \n', '20.SsangYong\n', '21.Cadillac \n', '22.Fiat\n', '23.Aston Martin\n', '24.Mercedes\n', '25.Mochi \n', '26.Mclaren \n', '27.Infiniti \n', '28.Lotus\n', '29.Bentley \n', '30.Maserati\n', '31.Ferrari \n', '32.Honda\n', '33.Nissan\n', '34.Haval\n', '35.Ford\n', '36.Volvo\n', '37.Seat\n', '38.Toyota\n', '39.Perodua \n', '40.Geely \n', '41.Mitsubishi \n', '41.Alfa Romeo \n', '42.Dahitsau\n', '43.Volkswagen\n', '44.Porsche \n', '45.Hyundai \n', '46.Bugatti\n', '47.Lamborghini\n', '48.Rolls Royce \n', '49.Suzuki\n', '50.Tesla']

So basically, is there a way to remove the commas, spaces and new line. ?

Comment: You can `map()` your functions onto list elements, or use a list comprehension to apply whatever transformations you want to each list element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with using the functions you mentioned, and that you can not apply them to a list data type. What you can do however, is iterate over the list and execute those functions against the content of the list.

```py
data_arr = ['2. Skoda\n', '3. Opel\n']
junk_chars = list(",.\n")
for i, entry in enumerate(data_arr):
  for junk_char in junk_chars:
    entry = entry.replace(junk_char, "")
  data_arr[i] = entry
```

I would advise against list comprehensions in this context given that you are not replacing a single character per entry, however, if you wanted to, you could run something like this:

```py
data_arr = ['2. Skoda\n', '3. Opel\n']
data_arr = [entry.replace(",","").replace("\n","") for entry in data_arr]
```

You could also use map() as per the comment above:

```py
def clean_entries(entry: str) -> str:
 junk_chars = list(",.\n")
 for junk_char in junk_chars:
   entry = entry.replace(junk_char, "")
 return entry

data_arr = ['2. Skoda\n', '3. Opel\n']
data_arr = map(clean_entries, data_arr)
```

Comment: thanks for the guide.... you guys are the best. All options worked, but the list comprehension was the best option and most straight forward. i learnt something new today again. But for further knowledge how come those functions workd inside a "list comprehension" but not by itself. any idea why?

Comment: Sure thing. A list comprehension is the equivalent of saying "do this operation on every element in the list". What happens when you combine that with something like replace() is that it runs that operation on every entry in the list. If you run replace() on the entire list, you are not working with a datatype that replace() can understand, since it can only work on single strings.

Comment: thanks again @SilverNitratelon. you have been most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to utilize Regex

```
import re
oldList = ['2. Skoda\n', '3. Opel\n', '4. Audi\n', '5. Isuzu\n', '6. Acura\n', '7. Subaru \n', '8. Jaguar \n', '9. Jeep\n','10.Mazda\n', '11.Mini\n', '12.Land Rover\n', '13.Lexus\n', '14.Saab\n', '15.Peugeot \n', '16.Renault \n', '17.Proton\n', '18.Daewoo \n', '19.Citroen \n', '20.SsangYong\n', '21.Cadillac \n', '22.Fiat\n', '23.Aston Martin\n', '24.Mercedes\n', '25.Mochi \n', '26.Mclaren \n', '27.Infiniti \n', '28.Lotus\n', '29.Bentley \n', '30.Maserati\n', '31.Ferrari \n', '32.Honda\n', '33.Nissan\n', '34.Haval\n', '35.Ford\n', '36.Volvo\n', '37.Seat\n', '38.Toyota\n', '39.Perodua \n', '40.Geely \n', '41.Mitsubishi \n', '41.Alfa Romeo \n', '42.Dahitsau\n', '43.Volkswagen\n', '44.Porsche \n', '45.Hyundai \n', '46.Bugatti\n', '47.Lamborghini\n', '48.Rolls Royce \n', '49.Suzuki\n', '50.Tesla']
newList = []
for str in oldList:
    newList.append(re.sub(r'[, \n]+', "", str))
print(newList)
```

I noticed that it removes the spaces in between words as well. Alfa Romeo becomes AlfaRomeo and Rolls Royce becomes RollsRoyce. Something to note